# PyPDF's PdfFileReader() having problems reading file, file not callable

Tags: python, file-io, pypdf

So here is my import:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
```

Here is were I write my pdf:

```
filenamer = filename + '.pdf'
pdf = PdfPages(filenamer)
```

(great naming convention, I know!)

I write some things to it.

I close it here:

```
pdf.close()
```

Here is where I try and read it:

```
input1 = PdfFileReader(file(filenamer, "rb"))
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./datamine.py", line 405, in <module>
    input1 = PdfFileReader(file(filenamer, "rb"))
TypeError: 'file' object is not callable
```

I dont understand the error, because I know the file exists, and when I comment out this line, and subsequent lines to input1, the program runs fine.

Comment: I don't know `pyPdf` but the general advice in Python is to use `open` rather than `file`. `file` has been removed as a builtin in Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've assigned an open file to the name `file`, and then you can't use the builtin any more.

Comment: It really does not like using file as a name.  I found it in a loop, where the scope didn't reach... so that is a weird!

Comment: Keep in mind: loops don't create a new scope as they do in C.  Names are local to an entire function, or global to the entire module.