# TypeError: 'PdfFileWriter' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf, pdf-writer

I am trying to extract specific pages from a PDF file, and save it in a different file name.
Followed the codes provided here :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6Gt57b3Pp4&t=219s

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
pdf_file_path = "oranges.pdf"
file_base_name = pdf_file_path.replace(".pdf","")

pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file_path) #Creating PDF instance
pages = [0,2,4]

pdfwriter = PdfFileWriter() #Creating pdfWriter instance
print

for page_num in pages:
    pdfwriter().addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num))
with open("{0}_subset".format(file_base_name),'wb') as f:
    pdfwriter.write(f)
    f.close
```

However I am getting this error in line 12:
TypeError: 'PdfFileWriter' object is not callable
How should I resolve this error?

Comment: Check this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045606/pypdfs-pdffilereader-having-problems-reading-file-file-not-callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a method invocation on an object unless the object points to a method.

Change the line `pdfwriter().addPage()` to `pdfwriter.addPage()`

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
pdf_file_path = "oranges.pdf"
file_base_name = pdf_file_path.replace(".pdf","")

pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file_path) #Creating PDF instance
pages = [0,2,4]

pdfwriter = PdfFileWriter() #Creating pdfWriter instance


for page_num in pages:
    pdfwriter.addPage(pdf.getPage(page_num))

with open("{0}_subset".format(file_base_name),'wb') as f:
    pdfwriter.write(f)
    f.close()
```